IConfiguration.Get return default property value for IReadOnlyCollection
I got a strange behaviour when try to get collection in configuration from appsettings.json using .NET 6.
My Class:
public record SomeOptions
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> SomeColl { get; init; } = new List<string> { "wrongString" };
}

My appsettings.json:
{
  "Some": {
    "SomeColl": [ "expectedString" ]
  }
}

Then I try get values like this:
var section = configuration.GetSection("Some");
var options = section.Get<SomeOptions>();

I got default value from property (wrongString). But if change property to be like:
public record SomeOptions
{
    public IReadOnlyCollection<string> SomeColl { get; init; } = null!;
}

Or
public record SomeOptions
{
    public ICollection<string> SomeColl { get; init; } = new List<string>();
}

I got value from appsettings.json (expectedString). Can someone explain please - why this is happenning?

Would not public required IReadOnlyCollection<string> SomeColl { get; init; } be correct rather than assigning it dummy value?

@Magnus It's not, because I want to set it to be non-nullable. But if JSON have empty collection "SomeColl": [ ] it treated as null =(

That I did not know, seem like using the JsonSerializer might be a better idea than Configuration library.

This part of the source code covers that:
if (config.GetChildren().Any())
{
    // for arrays and read-only list-like interfaces, we concatenate on to what is already there, if we can
    if (type.IsArray || IsImmutableArrayCompatibleInterface(type))
    {
        if (!bindingPoint.IsReadOnly)
        {
            bindingPoint.SetValue(BindArray(type, (IEnumerable?)bindingPoint.Value, config, options));
        }

        // for getter-only collection properties that we can't add to, nothing more we can do
        return;
    }


for arrays and read-only list-like interfaces, we concatenate on to what is already there, if we can

Though I could not find this being documented.
You can try reporting it @github but highly likely it would not be acted on as breaking change.
My guess that this is done to support hierarchical configs (i.e. when array elements are defined in multiple configuration sources, though not sure that this is also a good idea and sometimes leads to unexpected behavior).

Thanks! Forgot to say - I'm using .net 6. So some changes was made in ConfigurationBinder. But look like in .net 6 logic works similar to - If it is a readonly type and already initialized - return initialized instanse, since the type IS readonly
